# Building akka fails on "Error: could not retrieve JNA"

Tags: git, scala, build, sbt, akka

I tried to build akka as described on the website (http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.2/dev/building-akka.html) but was unsuccessful.

I'm running Windows 7 with cygwin, sbt 0.11.0 and scala 2.9.1. Here is the sequence of steps I followed:

```
git clone git://github.com/jboner/akka.git
git clone git://github.com/jboner/akka-modules.git
cd akka
sbt.bat update
```

The last command fails with the following error:

```
$ sbt.bat update

C:\Users\***\Desktop\akka>set SCRIPT_DIR=C:\SBT\

C:\Users\***\Desktop\akka>java -Xmx512M -jar "C:\SBT\sbt-launch.jar" update
Getting net.java.dev.jna jna 3.2.3 ...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
                module not found: net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3

        ==== local: tried

          C:\Users\***\.ivy2/local/net.java.dev.jna/jna/3.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml

        ==== Maven2 Local: tried

          file://C:\Users\***/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom

        ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

          http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/net.java.dev.jna/jna/3.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml

        ==== Maven Central: tried

          http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom

        ==== Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository: tried

          http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom

        ==== Scala-Tools Maven2 Snapshots Repository: tried

          http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                :: net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3: not found

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
        Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/net.java.dev.jna/jna/3.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml

        Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom

        Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom

        Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom


:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
unresolved dependency: net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
  (see C:\Users\***\.sbt\boot\update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve JNA
```

With sbt 0.7.7, I get the following (it prompts for a name):

```
./sbt.bat update

C:\Users\***\Desktop\akka>set SCRIPT_DIR=C:\Users\***\Desktop\akka\

C:\Users\***\Desktop\akka>java -Xmx512M -jar "C:\Users\***\Desktop\akka\sbt-launch.jar" update
Name:
```

Am I doing something wrong? Can you help me fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wait: https://github.com/jboner/akka/blob/master/project/build.properties Could it be possible that their documentation reflects sbt0.77, while their build request sbt0.11 (and you are using 0.10)? Only akka modules seem t request 0.77: https://github.com/jboner/akka-modules/blob/master/project/build.properties

Comment: I'm actually using 0.11 and it doesn't work (whether with 0.7.7 or 0.11)

Comment: Ok. just checking. Still looking that issue up.

Comment: Considering http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom is a valid address, wouldn't you have some internet connection issue? A proxy maybe? I have edited my answer to reflect that possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Note, the akka compilation instructions in the section "[SBT interactive mode](http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.2/dev/building-akka.html#sbt-interactive-mode)" seem to reference an old sbt

```
% sbt
[info] Building project akka 1.2 against Scala 2.9.1
[info]    using AkkaParentProject with sbt 0.7.6 and Scala 2.7.7
                                       ^^^^^^^^^
                                       |
                                       --- no xsbt 0.10+ here...
```

But the akka [`build.properties`](https://github.com/jboner/akka/blob/master/project/build.properties) does reference an sbt 0.11.0.

Considering that http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom is a valid address, I would suggest checking any internet issue (like a proxy not set for the sbt session).

Comment: Using sbt 0.7.7, it prompts for "Name:"

Comment: @LordPhoenix: is there an error message? If so, you can update your question with the relevant section, for me or other more experienced Scala users to analyse.

Comment: I added the error message with 0.7.7 to the original question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same kind of problem (module not found in central repos), and disabling ipv6 on my network interface solved my problem... It looks like accessing repos through ipv6 is not working well so far

Comment: You can accomplish the same thing with the VM argument java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true; either by adding it to the sbt.bat or by setting the JAVA_OPTS environment variable.  Run 'sbt -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true' as a test.

Answer (score 1):

Similar error. In my case this is related using http when https is required